# Histogram with multiple plots of same data

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram with an x-axis showing a range. I want the x-axis to be labelled with the data `IL2`, `IL3` and `IL4`. There are 4 points plotted at `IL3` and I want them to appear as separate bars in my histogram. I have this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=5pt,
    bar width=17pt,
    ylabel={Repair time (months)},
    symbolic y coords={$<$ 1 month, $>$ 1 month, 3 months, $>$ 3 months},
    ytick=data,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    xtick={IL2,IL3,IL3,IL3,IL3,IL4},
    ymajorgrids=true
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(6,$<$ 1 month) (5,$>$ 1 month) (4,$>$ 1 month) (3,3 months) (2,3 months) (1,$>$ 3 months)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces the following graph:

[image: producedgraph]

But I want the data in a range, showing that there are 4 points at `IL3`, like in the following graph. Do you know how I can do this in LaTeX?

[image: desiredgraph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your example gives an error, I think due to the combination of `symbolic x coords={<something>}` and `xtick={<something else>}`. The `xtick` key is for defining the x-values where you want to have a tick, but your list of ticks is different from the coordinates you have defined with `symbolic x coord`. Perhaps you were after `xticklabels={...}`, the purpose of that is to define the actual text printed as labels.

But back to the question. This is a little bit hacky, but it does give you the output asked for. I removed the `symbolic x coords` bit, I think it makes it easier if you use numeric coordinates (which you had in your `\addplot` anyway). I use `xtick` to add ticks between the bars, at appropriate places, and then I use `extra x ticks` to add labels between the ticks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% you already have some compat setting in your document, so please keep that, and remove the following line
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=5pt,
    bar width=17pt,
    ylabel={Repair time (months)},
    symbolic y coords={$<$ 1 month, $>$ 1 month, 3 months, $>$ 3 months},
    ytick=data,
    % set x-limits explicitly
    xmin=0.5,xmax=6.51,
    % add ticks at appropriate x-values
    xtick={0.5,1.5,5.5,6.5},
    % don't print any labels at the default ticks
    xticklabels={},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    % add some extra ticks where you want the labels
    extra x ticks={1,3.5,6},
    % set the labels
    extra x tick labels={IL2,IL3,IL4},
    % hide the ticks themselves
    extra x tick style={tickwidth=0}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(6,$<$ 1 month) (5,$>$ 1 month) (4,$>$ 1 month) (3,3 months) (2,3 months) (1,$>$ 3 months)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution - this works perfectly!